# What is android GestureDetector long tap timeout?

Tags: android, gesture

What is android `GestureDetector` `onLongTap` timeout? i need to invoke another event when the user pressed down and started moving (to distinguish between "down and move" and "down and hold" cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the sources of GestureDetector:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/GestureDetector.java? :

```
private static final int LONGPRESS_TIMEOUT = ViewConfiguration.getLongPressTimeout();
```

for my device it's 500 (500ms).

Answer (score 2):

So far i got to know about Gesture Detecter is that,Android's `GestureDetector` has a 300 ms timeout to distinguish between single and double taps. If the second tap has not occurred for 300ms, onSingleTapConfirmed is called.

For more information follow these links:

http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=2871

http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/help/gesturedetector.html

Hope this would provide some help..:)